# About operator overload resolution

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

Suppose two classes with the following implicit and explicit operator pattern:

```
class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator decimal (Foo foo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo (decimal value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static Foo operator +(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public static explicit operator decimal (Bar bar)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static explicit operator Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now consider the following code:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
var resultFooAddBar = foo + (decimal)bar;
```

The implicitly typed `resutlFooAddBar` resolves to `Foo` and the add operator resolves to `Foo Foo.operator +`. Why doesn't this code give an ambiguous error? The operator could have resolved equally to `decimal decimal.operator +`. Is it because user defined operators are *always* considered a better fit? Even so, the choice seems a bit weird, considering that `Bar` has an explicit cast to `Foo` that was not used which would explicitly define what operator the programmer would want to use:

`var resultFooAddBar = foo + (Foo)bar;` //OK, I'm explicitly saying I want `Foo Foo.operator +`

If instead of `decimal` we use a third class `Tango` defining a `Tango Tango.operator + (Tango, Tango)` and the same implicit and explicit operator patterns then an ambigous call error is thrown by the compiler.

Why this differentiation between user defined operators and non user defined operators?

*UPDATE*: I've created a separate assembly including the following class to try out Servy's exlanation:

```
namespace ExternalAssembly
{
    public class Tango
    {
        public static Tango operator +(Tango left, Tango right)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then changed `decimal` to `Tango` in `Foo` and `Bar` and adding the needed reference to the ExternalAssembly dll. In this case I'm still getting a *'+' operator is ambiguous on operands 'ConsoleApplication.Foo' and 'ExternalAssembly.Tango'*. Why wouldn't the compiler, in this case, choose the same overload `Foo Foo.operator +` as in my original question with `decimal`?

Comment: @Servy `decimal` + `decimal`. There is an implicit conversion from `Foo` to `decimal`, but the compiler instead chooses the implicit conversion from `decimal` to `Foo`. See last paragraph (just editted).

Answer (score 1):

The overload resolution algorithms have a series of "betterness" metrics by which they determine which of mutiple applicable overloads of a method/operator should be used.  It is only if none of those metrics has a conclusively "best" overload that there is an ambiguity error shown.

One of the metrics for betterness is the "closeness" of the definition of the overload in question to the call site.  A definition in the same class is "closer" than a definition outside of it, a definition in an outer class is closer than definitions outside of that parent type, definitions in the same namespace are closer than definitions in outer namespaces, etc.  Your definition is "closer" than the decimal's `+` operator.  (See [this article](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/) for more information on the subject.)

Comment: Ok that is what I more or less expected seeing how the operator resolution behaved. But still, it seems to me that like in all designs, there are compromises to not make it excessively complicated. In this case having an explicit cast that you choose not to use should be some kind of flag for the compiler to realize that maybe it's not choosing the "best" operator. Anyhow, there is saying in my country, *perfection is the enemy of goodness*, so the way it works is probably the best.

Comment: If I create say a `Tango` class in a seperate assembly and with a different namespace I'm still getting an ambiguous call. Why would it be any different than `decimal` in that case?